# Flexslider thumbnail carousel active class is not working properly

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I'm trying to implement Slider with text as control nav instead of thumbnail using flexslider. Everything is working fine but the carousel slider synced with main slider is not getting the 'flex-active-slide' class properly. The first 'li' is getting the class name but not for others.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(window).load(function(){
            jQuery( '#carousel' ).flexslider({
                 animation: "slide",
                animationLoop: false,
                controlNav: false,
                directionNav: false,
                slideshow: false,
                direction: "vertical",
                asNavFor: '#flexslider'
            });

            jQuery( '#flexslider' ).flexslider({
                animation: 'slide',
                slideshowSpeed: 4000,
                animationSpeed: 600,
                pauseOnAction: true,
                pauseOnHover: false,
                controlNav: false,
                directionNav: false,
                prevText: 'Previous',
                nextText: 'Next',
                controlsContainer: 'flexslider',
                sync: "#carousel"
            });
        });
            </script>
<div id="flexslider" class="flexslider" style="height:auto;">
<ul class="slides">
<li>
<a href="#">
<img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="Revitalising govt schools" class="ca-image"  /></a>
<div class="content">
<a href="#">Revitalising govt schools</a><div class='go-more'><p class='sub-text'>Let's educate for a better world</p><a href='#' class='more'>Please Donate</a></div></div>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" title="Revitalising govt schools">
<img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="Revitalising govt schools" class="ca-image"  /></a>
<div class="content">
<a href="#" title="Revitalising govt schools">Revitalising govt schools</a><div class='go-more'><p class='sub-text'>Let's educate for a better world</p><a href='#' class='more'>Please Donate</a></div></div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li>
<div class="excerpt"><p>This will be the excerpt text for this space</p></div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="excerpt"><p>This will be the excerpt text for this space 2</p></div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is how I have coded. I am able to control the slider using the text carousel but the active slide indicator is just not happening for anything other than the first carousel slide. Flexslider version used it 2.7.1

**Update**

Just made a demo on this issue for your easy reference. 
https://codepen.io/haridev/pen/MqJErr

Comment: You create a demo and share. So, it is easier for all to assist you.

Comment: However try this https://codepen.io/nerodev/pen/GXrmLq You need to write some custom CSS.

Comment: I just tried to replicate this on a demo. The issue looks like this. https://codepen.io/haridev/pen/MqJErr
See the carousel selector. Active slide appears only for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I took the example that flexslider offers from its site and modified to add text insead of images and its working as it should have.

the `.flex-active-slide` class its changing as it should have, so you can use that modify the css and adjust to your needs.

```
<!-- Place somewhere in the <body> of your page -->
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
    </li>
    <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      This will be the excerpt text for this space
    </li>
    <li>
      This will be the excerpt text for this space 2
    </li>
    <li>
      This will be the excerpt text for this space 3
    </li>
    <li>
      This will be the excerpt text for this space 4
    </li>
    <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

and jQuery

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // The slider being synced must be initialized first
  $('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  });

  $('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel"
  });
});
```

Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yxgjeB

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could fix the issue. I didn't set Itemwidth and Itemmargin properties which cause the issue. The update code looks like this

```
            jQuery(window).load(function(){
            jQuery( '#carousel' ).flexslider({
                 animation: "slide",
                animationLoop: false,
                controlNav: false,
                directionNav: false,
                slideshow: false,
                itemWidth: 580,
                        itemMargin: 5,
                asNavFor: '#flexslider'
            });

            jQuery( '#flexslider' ).flexslider({
                animation: 'fade',
                slideshowSpeed: 4000,
                animationSpeed: 600,
                pauseOnAction: true,
                pauseOnHover: false,
                controlNav: true,
                directionNav: false,
                prevText: 'Previous',
                nextText: 'Next',
                controlsContainer: 'flexslider',
                sync: "#carousel"
            });
        });
            </script>
```

Thank you all for your effort and contribution.